# Reducing the applet loading time

Tags: java, html, jar, applet

I have an html file which has a jar file included in it as an applet. When ever i am opening the html file its getting too much time to load the applet.

Is there any way by which i can reduce this loading time??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's at three major factors in play here.

**1)** Java startup time. Cold start used to be 5-10 seconds, however this has changed with the **[Java quickstarter](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/chet/archive/2007/05/consumer_jre_le.html#Quickstarter)** which was part of the Java 1.6 update 10. This is on by default for Windoes XP and 2000 (Vista offers its own pre-loading mechanisms), but maybe you have this disabled ([enable information](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/quickstarter.xml)).

**2)** The download time for your applet. Test it locally and if the startup time is significantly different consider using better compression techniques. **[Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)** will obfuscate code and reduce the code size by [upto 90 percent](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/results.html). 90Kb shouldn't be slow, but this could depend on your network speed and host.

**3)** The code you're using to initialize the applet. You could temporarily change your `init` method to just show a hello world button to identify if that is a problem. If you're not happy with the performance you may need to profile your code.

Applet startup time should be around a second (excluding download time). Check you have a fairly recent Java and try a simple [Hello World applet](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Pack 200](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/tools/pack200.html) to minimise the size of the JAR file.  How much difference this will make depends on how much of the time is spent downloading and how much is the start-up after download.

Answer (score -2):

If your startup time is too slow even when loaded locally, the only thing you can do is to switch to HTML5, Flash or Silverlight. I know it's a bit trolling, but the JVM/sandbox implementation is to blame and there is nothing you can do about it.

The SUN guys really didn't get the requirements for RIA-s. Of course it is always possible that Oracle will speed things up, but Applets are 15 years old and they are this slow since then.

Comment: I tried the HTML5 advice and I think it had a significant effect on my page load. but i still get a glitch every now and then, where it takes longer than other times.