# how to reduce the Applet jar downloading time?

Tags: java, applet

I am using Applet in web application, I have used 1.7.45 jdk in my local system, Applet jar file size is 3mb. When trying to download the 3mb applet jar file from cloud to local system it takes 9minutes.

I tried using proof of concept, created one sample applet jar file of 220kb. When downloading the same it only takes only 3sec from Cloud to local system.
I added some components like 3 testboxes and 1 button and the file jar size is 223kb and the time taken is 2 minutes from cloud to local system. When adding the coding

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
```

to the same file, the time taken to downloaded from cloud to local system is 7 minutes.
Please let me know how to reduce the downloading time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2319411/2722799 check this answer

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to split your issue into two parts.
1.How can i make my jar smaller in size ?
2.How can i make my jar load faster ?

**1.How can i make my jar smaller in size**

**Compress your JAR file by using the pack200 tool.**

(for detail about pack200 look into this link http://mythinkpond.com/2010/03/31/speeding-up-your-load-time-for-your-java-applets-and-webstart-applications/)

**Remove unnecessary white space**

**Optimize images and animation.**

**put all your code in one class (with no inner-classes): you lose elegance and data hiding, but all the strings necessary for internal linking will be removed.**

**make sure everything (methods & fields) that can be private is.**

**don't put your code into a package unless you really have to.**

**look at your identifiers (class, method and field names) - can you make them shorter?**

**Look for third party tool that shrink jars (Proguard) and look into obfuscators** .
**2.How can i make my jar load faster ?**

**Ask your self is the functionality suited to make this jar as a plugin for browsers. If yes it should certainly load faster.**

**Storing applet in client machines** ( http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076963/client-side-java/reduce-the-launch-time-of-your-applets--store-them-on-client-machines.html)